Detect connection usb device(storage) to IOS in MAUI
I have usb flash drive which connect to Iphone XR via adapter.
I want to detect when device was connected to Iphone.
I read this links and try to write something similar
xamarin link
swift link
 MyClass()
 {
     EAAccessoryManager? accessoryManager = EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager;
     accessoryManager?.RegisterForLocalNotifications();
     NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification"), AccessoryConnected);
     NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification"), AccessoryDisconnected);
 }
 void AccessoryConnected(NSNotification notification)
 {
    Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Connected!", "OK");
}
void AccessoryDisconnected(NSNotification notification)
{
    Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Disconnected!", "OK");
}

And AccessoryConnected/AccessoryDisconnected never triggered. May be wrong NSString in "AddObserver"?
P.S. List of all connected accessories to device always empty (even if i check it when flash drive was connected)
 var allAccessorries = accessoryManager?.ConnectedAccessories;

P.P.S. Also i try to get mounted volumes on device
NSFileManager? manager = new NSFileManager();
NSString[] parames = { NSUrl.VolumeNameKey };
NSUrl[] urls = manager.GetMountedVolumes(parames, 
NSVolumeEnumerationOptions.SkipHiddenVolumes);
foreach (var url in urls)
{
    Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Alert", url.ToString(), "OK");
}

And it crushes when try to get "url" from "urls" in foreach block. Did i need some permissons in info.plist or someething else for this?

An iOS app cannot directly access files outside its sandbox.  It is unlikely that a USB storage device will be MFi compatible - An MFi chipset is required for the device to be discoverable by the external connectivity framework.
